# How does web-server know which mime-type to set for resource?

Tags: php, web, webserver

When a browser receives a document from web-server, it reads `content-type` header and decides how to parse a file. I can explicitly set correct `content-type` for headers from scripts on server, but when web-server serves css or javascript files, it automatically sets correct mime-types. How does it know which type relates to which file? I suspect that it uses file extension to get correct mime type from some inner file.

Comment: It'd be easier if you said which server is of your particular interest. But to answer your question - yes, each server has some sort of local "database" that tells it what's the appropriate mime type for a certain file. As for how it's implemented in detail - there are many servers, you should pick one you're interested with and if it's OSS one - do a quick search of its source code to find out.

Comment: Thanks, I'm particularly interested in Apache server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which webserver you're using but apache uses a predefined list of file extensions to mime-types. You can alter or add to this list in the httpd.conf or a .htaccess file

Like so:
`AddType video/mp4 .mp4`